Cron job scheduled in spring app to distribute data with all instances
I have a design question
Cron job scheduled in spring app using @scheduled, I have 4 instances and I want the job to run in all the instances by distributing data. Say I need to process 1000 data, each instance should process 250 data.
Any idea how this can be achieved.
Instances are using kubernetes pod
Tried locking the data row level but this might not be a good approach

We had just the same issue and solved it by the solution described in https://vladmihalcea.com/database-job-queue-skip-locked/.
